# Warning message on statusBarStyle on set lightContent

Tags: swift, statusbar, uiapplication, uistatusbar

How to resolve this issue warning issue

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

Warning Messages

**'statusBarStyle' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Use the statusBarManager property of the window scene instead.**

Answer (score 2):

Use the `statusBarManager` ([UIStatusBarManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistatusbarmanager)):

Overwrite the `preferredStatusBarStyle` in your view controller and do this:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    .lightContent
}
```

You can have a `BaseViewController: UIViewController {}` class that controls that and make that all your VCs inherit from it.

Comment: Your first suggestion returns this error: `Cannot assign to property: 'statusBarStyle' is a get-only property`

Comment: Yeah, no longer changeable. It is now only possible with the preferred one: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistatusbarmanager/3213942-statusbarstyle

Answer (score 1):

for me it worked this way

```
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle { 
       return .lightContent 
    }
```

Comment: This isn't different from the answer above, the only difference is you're using the return keyword but that's not necessary when there's a single line response, it knows to return it.